# How to use join in sql for get desired result

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I have 2 tables orc_users and orc_files.
Now I want to fetch files of related users from orc_files table 
I have try this Query:-

```
use orc 
select * 
from orc_users as  T1 
INNER JOIN orc_files AS t2 on T1.id = t2.userid
where T1.email='sdfsdf';
```

and I got this result:-
[image]

but I want records something like:-

```
user={name:"sad",
      phone:"asdasda",
      files:[{filename:"dfsdfs",size:12,fileid:"sdfs"}, 
      {filename:"dfsdfs",size:12,fileid:"sdfs"}]}
```

I am using node.js with MySQL so it give me result in array.

please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all untested:
Use group_concat() for the comma separated string and group by in the query, like so:

```
select
        t1.id
        /* specify the fields here */

      , GROUP_CONCAT(T2.Filename
             ORDER BY T2.Filename ASC SEPARATOR ', ') as filenames

from orc_users as  T1 
INNER JOIN orc_files AS t2 on T1.id = t2.userid
where T1.email='sdfsdf'
group by
      t1.id
      /* specify the fields here too */
;
```

Try also using CONCAT() to get both filename and size, e.g.

```
      , GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(T2.Filename,' size:',T2.size)
             ORDER BY T2.Filename ASC SEPARATOR ', ') as filenames
```

If concat() inside the group_concat() works [I think it will] keep adding items until you get all the details required.

performance warning: no idea how well this would perform, might not be great.

Comment: CONCAT / CONCAT_WS within a GROUP_CONCAT does work (I have used them quite often). The potential issue is if a field you concatenate in has a null value. It is possible to directly build up a php serialised array in SQL using this method (probably not recommended though for maintenance reasons).

Comment: Thanks, I was fairly confident it would work and wasn't able to test at the time. So IFNULL() needs to be used also. Good advice.

Answer (score 0):

There is no possible to get that result in a single query, but you can get `files` data in each individual row as query and attach it results into current row.

Comment: yes I know that but I was hoping for single query. btw thank you for your help